# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined--

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var morgan = require("morgan");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
port = 8000;
var User = require("./app/models/user");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/tutorial", function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Disconnected: " + err);
  } else {
    console.log("connected");
  }
});
app.post("/users", function (req, res) {
  var user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.save();
  res.send("user created");
});
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("You are listen on port " + port);
});
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
at D:\MEAN\server.js:16:28
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at query (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 0):

Include a code to grab the request body using express method express.json which uses body parser module behind the scenes
E.g

This should work

---

app.use(express.json())

Answer (score 0):

If your post request comes as json as I presume it does you are going to need to somehow parse the request's body. You can do that by requiring "body-parser" and using it's json method like so:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = require('express')();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

What we're saying with `app.use(bodyParser.json())` is to use that body parser for every single route.